# function for links in content that was added with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a one-page design

I have all content "pages" in separate divs, then I hide them all with jquery

When clicking a menu item, the pageholder's inner content is switched using html()

But I can't use click() or on("click") on the pages..
Because it's dynamically added and has a different scope?

Let's say I have something like this:

```
$("#menu #somepagebutton").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("#pageholder").hide().html($("#somepage").html()).fadeIn();;
});
```

There are some links inside the div with id "somepage"

Then using this, does not work:

```
$("#pageholder a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("test");
});
```

It's simply not fired

How can I adjust it so it works on content added by jquery too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event delegation:

```
$("#pageholder").on("click", "a", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("test");

});
```

Comment: so the "a" is any anchor link, or? Can I put anything there?

Comment: @mowgli -- in the code above it targets `anchors` - but you can replace that with any dynamic element loaded within `#pageholder`

Comment: The solution is the exact same as `("#pageholder a").click(function(e) {` The reason your code wasnt working @mowgli is because your pageloader html is being added dynamically.. so events must be delegated.

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy.. untill I finally realized it had to do with the content being dynamically added :)

Comment: So.. using $("#pageholder").click("a") Is not the way? It has to be on("click")?

Comment: @mowgli -- Yes, for dynamically loaded content. The handlers are bound at runtime - so at runtime if there is no content in `#pageholder` your handlers are bound to nothing. Using `.on` binds a click to `#pageholder` and each time the click happens, it will actively look for the specified target element (dynamic or static)

Comment: Ok. I will use on("click") on dynamic content. And click() on all other.. or is it best to use on("click") overall?

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach event handlers to the page elements that are loaded dynamically. You should find that jquery's .on function works nicely for this.

Here's everything you need to know ( almost ) about how to use it:

http://api.jquery.com/on/